# No entry in GRUB to boot!

Tags: system-installation, boot, dual-boot

I have a computer with the following specs -

- Intel Pentium E2180
- 945GCM S2L board
- 2 hdd's namely

  - Seagate Momentus SpinPoint with windows 7 on sda1 , an extended partition sda4 containing 346GB data , 186 GB EXT4(Elementary) , 155 GB (Ubuntu 15.10) and sda8(linux-swap)
  - Seagate Barracuda ATA IV with Windows XP Home

I wanted linux on my PC after windows failed . I liked ubuntu and elementary and decided to install both . Ubuntu installed like a charm and works well . Elementary , I did the same thing . I selected SDA as bootloader device and the 186GB empty ext4 partition as / . The install continued for a while , and I was not at my PC . When I came back , the system was in this weird state , with a mouse pointer and cursor in the top left blinking . I mananged to switch to tty1 and reboot to ubuntu . I saw in this partition that all directories had been created , so I shut down and looked at GRUB . There was no elementary entry only Ubuntu 15.10 and my windows installs . Now what do I do ?  I have a live copy of Elementary Freya 0.3.2.

Comment: Try installing again.Also why do you still use XP :)

Comment: I figured it out - i had to run 'update-grub' in ubuntu . I don't actually use XP , I was just recovering some data from it :)

Comment: Then recover the data and remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will have grub look for Operating Systems installed on your machine and then update its boot list.